# Inserting multiple rows linked by fk - php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, oracle, pdo

I'm trying to insert the data from the form into the table teams, with all team names and the fk to each age group. 
I'm getting the age group id from a simple SELECT function and then looping the id's over the form.
When i run the insert function, i'm only getting 4 rows from the first form with the data.
so if there was 3,4 or 5 different age groups, I would like to insert the names and the age_group fk for alle groups

The form and age group loop:

```
<form action="" method="post">
   <?php
      $ages = get_age_groups_in_cups($db);
         foreach($ages as $age){
   ?>

   <input type="text" name="age_group[]" value="<?php echo $age['age_id'];?>">
   <input type="text" name="team_name[]">
   <input type="text" name="team_name[]">
   <input type="text" name="team_name[]">
   <input type="text" name="team_name[]">

   <?php
     }
   ?>

   <button name="insert_rows">save</button>
</form>
```

i'm running the insert function when insert button has been submitted, but i'm only getting the result from the "first" age_group

the function:

```
function insert_teams($db){
    $age_group = $_POST['age_group'];
    $team_name = $_POST['team_name'];

    foreach ($age_group as $key => $error){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO teams (team_name, age_group_fk) VALUES (:team_name, :age_group_fk)";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(array(
            'team_name' => $team_name,
            'age_group_fk' => $age_group[$key]
            ));
        }

    }
```

Comment: How do you think, what are the sizes of these two arrays?

Comment: @YourCommonSense if there's only one age group the array for age is 0 and contains the age number, and the team_name is 0123 long. if there is more groups, the team_name is then 8, 12, 16 ect, and age is as long as there are age groups

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Can you tell just straight, what are  the sizes of these two arrays?

Comment: here is a print_r of the posted data. from team 1 - team 4 should be in age_group 1, and the rest in age_group 4 Array
(
    [age_group] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 4
        )

    [team_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => team 1
            [1] => team 2
            [2] => team 3
            [3] => team 4
            [4] => team 5
            [5] => team 6
            [6] => team 7
            [7] => team 8
        )

    [newStepTwo] => 
)

Answer (score 0):

You should add a level on your input array.

You use `<input type="text" name="team_name[]">` for each age group.

But basically all age groups will be in the same array.

Use instead something like

```
<?php
    <form action="#" method="post">
       <?php
     $ages = get_age_groups_in_cups($db);
             foreach($ages as $age){
       ?>

       <input type="text" name="team_name[<?= $age['age_id'] ?>][]">
       <input type="text" name="team_name[<?= $age['age_id'] ?>][]">
       <input type="text" name="team_name[<?= $age['age_id'] ?>][]">
       <input type="text" name="team_name[<?= $age['age_id'] ?>][]">

       <?php
         }
       ?>

       <button name="insert_rows">save</button>
    </form>
```